Concatenate CSV files
I want to concatenate ASCII CSV files with identical header lines, skipping the header line for files 2 etc...
Is there a faster way than this old-fashioned one?
AssignFile(lOutFile,lOutputFileName);
ReWrite(lOutFile);
for j := 0 to lFileURLs.Count-1 do
begin
  AssignFile(lInFile,lFileURLs[j]);
  Reset(lInFile);
  lTop := true;
  while not eof(lInFile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(lInFile,lLine);
    if (j=0) or (not lTop) then WriteLn(lOutFile,lLine);
    lTop := false;
  end;
  CloseFile(lInFile);
end;
CloseFile(lOutFile);

IIRC, I can increase the file buffer size for speed, but is there anything else that's significantly faster? TStringList?
Real world scenario is 5-10 files of 100-300 KiB, in a 32 and 64 bit VCL app.
(There are plenty of questions here about concatenating CSVs, especially in Python, but I could not find an answer that helps in Delphi.)

Observations: Past the header line you can just block copy the rest - no need to go line by line. The headers are all the same size in bytes (or should be - if they are not that would an error of some type). Could use streams and just skip past the header bytes for the second file onwards.

@Brian OK, lemme try that. Just scan for the first CR and or LF and remember that position for the other files. That will even work if the files are not plain ASCII (i.e. have a BOM)

Who in this century would decide to use the old '80s style file I/O to do anything? TStringList if the files are not huge, or TFileStream or one of its descendants, would be preferable choices.

Ken's comment was correct, TBufferedFileStream outperforms TStringList which outperforms old fashioned text file I/O (which was no surprise).
Typical results for a test set with 9 CSV files totalling 10MB (all in Windows buffers): 20, 200 and 400 msec.
Below is the code for a 32-bits VCL test app.
Note that TBufferedFileStream does not 'correct' a missing CRLF at the end of the input files, the other two do.
PAS file
    unit uConcatCSV;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IOUtils, System.Types, System.Diagnostics;

    type
      TFrmConcatCSV = class(TForm)
        Memo1: TMemo;
        BtnTextFileIO: TButton;
        BtnFileStream: TButton;
        EdtOutputFile: TEdit;
        Label1: TLabel;
        BtnTStringList: TButton;
        procedure BtnTextFileIOClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure BtnFileStreamClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
        procedure BtnTStringListClick(Sender: TObject);
      private
        FCRLFPos: Integer;
        FCurrDir: String;
        FCSVFiles: TStringDynArray;
        procedure CollectFiles;
        procedure ConcatTextFiles;
        procedure ConcatFileStreams;
        procedure ConcatstringLists;
      public
      end;

    var
      FrmConcatCSV: TFrmConcatCSV;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TFrmConcatCSV.BtnFileStreamClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       CollectFiles;
       ConcatFileStreams;
    end;

    procedure TFrmConcatCSV.BtnTextFileIOClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       CollectFiles;
       ConcatTextFiles;
    end;

    procedure TFrmConcatCSV.BtnTStringListClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       CollectFiles;
       ConcatStringLists;
    end;

    procedure TFrmConcatCSV.CollectFiles;
    begin
       Memo1.Clear;
       FCSVFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles(FCurrDir, '*.csv');
       Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Length(FCSVFiles)) + ' files detected');
    end;

    procedure TFrmConcatCSV.ConcatFileStreams;
    // A missing CRLF at EOF will NOT be added
    var
       lInFS,
       lOutFS   : TBufferedFileStream;
       lBufSize,
       j        : Integer;
       lFileName: String;
       lSW      : TStopWatch;
       B        : Byte;
    begin
       lSW := TStopWatch.StartNew;
       lOutFS := TBufferedFileStream.Create(FCurrDir + EdtOutputFile.Text,fmCreate or fmShareExclusive);
       for j := 0 to Length(FCSVFiles)-1 do
       begin
          lFileName := FCSVFiles[j];
          Memo1.Lines.Add(lFileName);
          lInFS := TBufferedFileStream.Create(lFileName,fmOpenRead or fmShareExclusive);
          lBufSize := lInFS.Size;
          lInFS.Position := 0;
          if j = 0 then
          begin  // Determine position after first CRLF
             repeat lInFS.Read(B,1)
             until B in [10,13];
             while B in [10,13] do
                lInFS.Read(B,1);
             FCRLFPos := lInFS.Position;
             lInFS.Position := 0;
             lOutFS.CopyFrom(lInFS,lBufSize);
          end
          else
          begin
             lInFS.Position := FCRLFPos-1;
             lOutFS.CopyFrom(lInFS,lBufSize-FCRLFPos+1);
          end;
          lInFS.Free;
       end;
       lOutFS.Free;
       lSW.Stop;
       Memo1.Lines.Add('msec: ' + lSW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString);
    end;

    procedure TFrmConcatCSV.ConcatstringLists;
    // A missing CRLF at EOF will be added
    var
       lTS        : TStringlist;
       j          : Integer;
       lOutName,
       lInName    : String;
       lOutFS     : TFileStream;
       lSW        : TStopWatch;
    begin
       lSW      := TStopWatch.StartNew;
       lTS      := TStringlist.Create;
       lOutName := FCurrDir + EdtOutputFile.Text;
       lOutFS := TFileStream.Create(lOutName, fmCreate or fmShareExclusive);
       for j := 0 to Length(FCSVFiles)-1 do
       begin
          lInName := FCSVFiles[j];
          Memo1.Lines.Add(lInName);
          lTS.LoadFromFile(lInName);  // Will detect encoding
          if j <> 0 then lTS.Delete(0);
          lTS.SaveToStream(lOutFS);
       end;
       lTS.Free;
       lSW.Stop;
       lOutFS.Free;
       Memo1.Lines.Add('msec: ' + lSW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString);
    end;

    procedure TFrmConcatCSV.ConcatTextFiles;
    // A missing CRLF at EOF will be added
    const
       cBufSize = 4096;
    var
       lOutFile,
       lInFile  : TextFile;
       lTop     : Boolean;
       lFileName,
       lLine    : String;
       j        : Integer;
       lSW      : TStopWatch;
       lInBuf,
       lOutBuf  : Array[1..cBufSize] of Byte;
    begin
       lSW := TStopWatch.StartNew;
       AssignFile(lOutFile,FCurrDir + EdtOutputFile.Text);
       System.SetTextBuf(lOutFile,lOutBuf);
       ReWrite(lOutFile);
       for j := 0 to Length(FCSVFiles)-1 do
       begin
          lFileName := FCSVFiles[j];
          Memo1.Lines.Add(lFileName);
          AssignFile(lInFile,lFileName);
          System.SetTextBuf(lInFile,lInBuf);
          Reset(lInFile);
          lTop := true;
          while not eof(lInFile) do
          begin
             ReadLn(lInFile,lLine);
             if (j=0) or not lTop then WriteLn(lOutFile,lLine);
             lTop := false;
          end;
          CloseFile(lInFile);
       end;
       CloseFile(lOutFile);
       lSW.Stop;
       Memo1.Lines.Add('msec: ' + lSW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString);
    end;

    procedure TFrmConcatCSV.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       FCurrDir := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(TDirectory.GetCurrentDirectory);
    end;

    end.

DFM file
    object FrmConcatCSV: TFrmConcatCSV
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Concatenate CSV files'
      ClientHeight = 441
      ClientWidth = 624
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
      Font.Style = []
      Position = poScreenCenter
      OnShow = FormShow
      TextHeight = 15
      object Label1: TLabel
        Left = 11
        Top = 412
        Width = 93
        Height = 15
        Caption = 'Output file name:'
      end
      object Memo1: TMemo
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Width = 624
        Height = 385
        Align = alTop
        TabOrder = 0
      end
      object BtnTextFileIO: TButton
        Left = 368
        Top = 408
        Width = 75
        Height = 25
        Caption = 'Text file I/O'
        TabOrder = 1
        OnClick = BtnTextFileIOClick
      end
      object BtnFileStream: TButton
        Left = 528
        Top = 408
        Width = 75
        Height = 25
        Caption = 'File streams'
        TabOrder = 2
        OnClick = BtnFileStreamClick
      end
      object EdtOutputFile: TEdit
        Left = 110
        Top = 410
        Width = 243
        Height = 23
        TabOrder = 3
        Text = 'output.txt'
      end
      object BtnTStringList: TButton
        Left = 447
        Top = 408
        Width = 75
        Height = 25
        Caption = 'TStringList'
        TabOrder = 4
        OnClick = BtnTStringListClick
      end
    end

BTW Correcting missing CRLFs at the end of the input files is not difficult, just before the lInFS.Free add:
  // Check if last byte is CR or LF, if not add CRLF
  // This assumes that *only* a CR or LF is enough
  lInFS.Position := lBufSize-1;
  lInFS.Read(B,1);
  if not (B in [10,13]) then
  begin
     B := 13; lOutFS.Write(B,1);
     B := 10; lOutFS.Write(B,1);
  end;

